# How to add special language symbols in the \section statements?

Tags: sectioning, pdftex, miktex, compiling, latexmk

I have the following document I found on [tcc/proposta.tex#L69](https://github.com/royertiago/tcc/blob/master/proposta.tex#L69)

Creating a minimal example, I removed everything except the `\section{Introdução}`:

```
% proposal.tex
% Based on http://www.latextemplates.com/template/simple-sectioned-essay
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx} % resizebox
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\linespread{1.5} % Line spacing

\begin{document}

\section{Introdução}

    Test.

\end{document}
```

But when I try to compile it, latex output the errors:

```
report.tex:21: Missing ) inserted for expression. [    \section{Introduo}]
report.tex:21: Missing ) inserted for expression. [    \section{Introduo}]
report.tex:21: Missing = inserted for \ifnum. [    \section{Introduo}]
report.tex:21: Missing number, treated as zero. [    \section{Introduo}]
report.tex:21: Package inputenc Error: Unicode char o (U+7) [    \section{Introduo}]
report.tex:21: Missing ) inserted for expression. [    \section{Introduo}]
report.tex:21: Missing ) inserted for expression. [    \section{Introduo}]
report.tex:21: Missing = inserted for \ifnum. [    \section{Introduo}]
report.tex:21: Missing number, treated as zero. [    \section{Introduo}]
report.tex:21: Extra \else. [    \section{Introduo}]
```

If I remove the special language symbols `çã` from the document, latex compiles and outputs correctly the document:

[image]

Therefore, how to make latex build the `\section{Introdução}`, instead of only `\section{Intruducao}`?

I am building it on Sublime Text, using the package `LaTeX Tools`. I can also use the command line `latexmk -pdf -output-directory="cache" -aux-directory="cache" -pdflatex="pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode" -use-make main.tex`.

---

## Update

I am on Windows with this MikTex version:

```
pdflatex --version
MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.6211 (1.40.17) (MiKTeX 2.9.6210)
Copyright (C) 1982 D. E. Knuth, (C) 1996-2016 Han The Thanh
TeX is a trademark of the American Mathematical Society.
using bzip2 version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010
compiled with curl version 7.52.1; using libcurl/7.52.1 WinSSL
compiled with expat version 2.2; using expat_2.2.0
compiled with jpeg version 9.2
compiled with liblzma version 50020022; using 50020022
compiled with libpng version 1.6.28; using 1.6.28
compiled with libressl version LibreSSL 2.4.4; using LibreSSL 2.4.4
compiled with MiKTeX Application Framework version 1.6211; using 1.6211
compiled with MiKTeX Core version 1.6216; using 1.6233
compiled with MiKTeX Archive Extractor version 1.6211; using 1.6211
compiled with MiKTeX Package Manager version 1.6218; using 1.6229
compiled with poppler version 0.50.0
compiled with uriparser version 0.8.4
compiled with zlib version 1.2.10; using 1.2.10
```

I build with the command line and still get the error:

```
latexmk -pdf -output-directory="cache" -aux-directory="cache" -pdflatex="pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode" -use-make report.tex
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 19 Jan. 2017, version: 4.52c.
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex': Rules & subrules not known to be previously run:
   pdflatex
Rule 'pdflatex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
      'pdflatex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode  -recorder -output-directory="cache"  "report.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210)
entering extended mode
(report.tex
LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 1
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\size12.clo))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\utf8.def
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\t1enc.dfu)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\ot1enc.dfu)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\omsenc.dfu)))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.cfg))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\babel\babel.sty
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\arabi\bblopts.cfg)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\babel-portuges\portuges.ldf
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\babel\babel.def)

Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for
(babel)                the language `Portuguese' into the format.
(babel)                Please, configure your TeX system to add them and
(babel)                rebuild the format. Now I will use the patterns
(babel)                preloaded for \language=0 instead on input line 55.

! Missing ) inserted for expression.
<to be read again>
                   (
l.21 \section{Introdu▒▒o}

! Missing ) inserted for expression.
<to be read again>
                   (
l.21 \section{Introdu▒▒o}

! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again>
                   (
l.21 \section{Introdu▒▒o}

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   (
l.21 \section{Introdu▒▒o}

! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ▒▒o (U+7)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.21 \section{Introdu▒▒o}

! Missing ) inserted for expression.
<to be read again>
                   (
l.21 \section{Introdu▒▒o}

! Missing ) inserted for expression.
<to be read again>
                   (
l.21 \section{Introdu▒▒o}

! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again>
                   (
l.21 \section{Introdu▒▒o}

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   (
l.21 \section{Introdu▒▒o}

! Extra \else.
\@sect ... {\csname the#1\endcsname }\fi #7}\else
                                                  \def \@svsechd {#6{\hskip ...
l.21 \section{Introdu▒▒o}

[1{D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/data/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(D:\User\Downloads\cache\report.aux) )
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 21 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 21 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifnum on line 21 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 21 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 21 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifdim on line 21 was incomplete)
(see the transcript file for additional information){D:/User/Documents/latex/te
xmfs/install/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}<D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/instal
l/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmb8a.pfb><D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/font
s/type1/urw/times/utmr8a.pfb>
Output written on D:/User/Downloads/cache/report.pdf (1 page, 15157 bytes).
Transcript written on D:/User/Downloads/cache/report.log.
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'cache/report.pdf'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'cache/report.log' for details
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex.
```

This is the `report.log` file generated:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.4.17)  21 APR 2017 15:53
entering extended mode
**./report.tex
(report.tex
LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 1
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\utf8.def
File: utf8.def 2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
Now handling font encoding OML ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OML
Now handling font encoding T1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding T1

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\t1enc.dfu
File: t1enc.dfu 2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A0 (decimal 160)
   defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
   defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
   ...
)
Now handling font encoding OT1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OT1

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\ot1enc.dfu
File: ot1enc.dfu 2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A0 (decimal 160)
   defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
   ...
)
Now handling font encoding OMS ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMS

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\omsenc.dfu
File: omsenc.dfu 2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
   defining Unicode char U+00B6 (decimal 182)
   defining Unicode char U+00B7 (decimal 183)
   defining Unicode char U+2020 (decimal 8224)
   defining Unicode char U+2021 (decimal 8225)
   defining Unicode char U+2022 (decimal 8226)
)
Now handling font encoding OMX ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMX
Now handling font encoding U ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding U
   defining Unicode char U+00A9 (decimal 169)
   defining Unicode char U+00AA (decimal 170)
   defining Unicode char U+00AE (decimal 174)
   defining Unicode char U+00BA (decimal 186)
   defining Unicode char U+02C6 (decimal 710)
   defining Unicode char U+02DC (decimal 732)
   defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
   defining Unicode char U+2026 (decimal 8230)
   defining Unicode char U+2122 (decimal 8482)
   defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2017/01/24 v2.0c Standard LaTeX package

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2017/01/24 v2.0c Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\Gm@cnth=\count87
\Gm@cntv=\count88
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count89
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen103
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen104
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen105
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen106
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen107
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen108
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen109
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen110
\Gm@dimlist=\toks17

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.cfg))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\babel\babel.sty
Package: babel 2016/04/23 3.9r The Babel package

*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\arabi\bblopts.cfg
File: bblopts.cfg 2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of
 babel
)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\babel-portuges\portuges.ldf
Language: portuges 2008/03/18 v1.2q Portuguese support from the babel system

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\babel\babel.def
File: babel.def 2016/04/23 3.9r Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count90
\U@D=\dimen111
)

Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for
(babel)                the language `Portuguese' into the format.
(babel)                Please, configure your TeX system to add them and
(babel)                rebuild the format. Now I will use the patterns
(babel)                preloaded for \language=0 instead on input line 55.

\l@portuges = a dialect from \language0
\l@brazil = a dialect from \language\l@portuges 
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 145.
)) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2016/10/09 v1.0u Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 99.

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\graphics-def\pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2017/01/12 v0.06k Graphics/color for pdfTeX

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count91
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen112
\Gin@req@width=\dimen113
)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\multirow\multirow.sty
Package: multirow 2016/11/25 v2.2 Span multiple rows of a table
\multirow@colwidth=\skip43
\multirow@cntb=\count92
\multirow@dima=\skip44
\bigstrutjot=\dimen114
)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\tools\tabularx.sty
Package: tabularx 2016/02/03 v2.11 `tabularx' package (DPC)

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\tools\array.sty
Package: array 2016/10/06 v2.4d Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen115
\extrarowheight=\dimen116
\NC@list=\toks18
\extratabsurround=\skip45
\backup@length=\skip46
)
\TX@col@width=\dimen117
\TX@old@table=\dimen118
\TX@old@col=\dimen119
\TX@target=\dimen120
\TX@delta=\dimen121
\TX@cols=\count93
\TX@ftn=\toks19
)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\psnfss\mathptmx.sty
Package: mathptmx 2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a Times w/ Math, improved (SPQR, WaS) 
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/ztmcm/m/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/ztmcm/m/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `letters' on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/ztmcm/m/it on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/ztmcm/m/it on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `symbols' on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/ztmcm/m/n on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/ztmcm/m/n on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `largesymbols' on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/ztmcm/m/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/ztmcm/m/n on input line 31.
\symbold=\mathgroup4
\symitalic=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathbf on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/ptm/bx/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/ptm/bx/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathit on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/ptm/m/it on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> OT1/ptm/m/it on input line 35.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \hbar on input line 50.
)
(D:\User\Downloads\cache\report.aux)
\openout1 = `report.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+ptm on input line 19.

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\psnfss\t1ptm.fd
File: t1ptm.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for T1/ptm.
)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: a4paper
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(56.9055pt, 483.69687pt, 56.9055pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(56.9055pt, 731.23584pt, 56.9055pt)
* \paperwidth=597.50787pt
* \paperheight=845.04684pt
* \textwidth=483.69687pt
* \textheight=731.23584pt
* \oddsidemargin=-15.36449pt
* \evensidemargin=-15.36449pt
* \topmargin=-52.36449pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=12.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=44.0pt
* \marginparsep=10.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.8pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count94
\scratchdimen=\dimen122
\scratchbox=\box26
\nofMPsegments=\count95
\nofMParguments=\count96
\everyMPshowfont=\toks20
\MPscratchCnt=\count97
\MPscratchDim=\dimen123
\MPnumerator=\count98
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count99
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks21
) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\grfext.sty
Package: grfext 2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
)) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
38.
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 456.
)
\big@size=\dimen124
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/ptm/bx/n' in size <17.28> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 21.


! Missing ) inserted for expression.
<to be read again> 
                   (
l.21 \section{Introdução}

I was expecting to see `+', `-', `*', `/', or `)'. Didn't.

! Missing ) inserted for expression.
<to be read again> 
                   (
l.21 \section{Introdução}

I was expecting to see `+', `-', `*', `/', or `)'. Didn't.

! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   (
l.21 \section{Introdução}

I was expecting to see `<', `=', or `>'. Didn't.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   (
l.21 \section{Introdução}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ção (U+7)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.21 \section{Introdução}

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

! Missing ) inserted for expression.
<to be read again> 
                   (
l.21 \section{Introdução}

I was expecting to see `+', `-', `*', `/', or `)'. Didn't.

! Missing ) inserted for expression.
<to be read again> 
                   (
l.21 \section{Introdução}

I was expecting to see `+', `-', `*', `/', or `)'. Didn't.

! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   (
l.21 \section{Introdução}

I was expecting to see `<', `=', or `>'. Didn't.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   (
l.21 \section{Introdução}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Extra \else.
\@sect ... {\csname the#1\endcsname }\fi #7}\else 
                                                  \def \@svsechd {#6{\hskip ...
l.21 \section{Introdução}

I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.

[1

{D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/data/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(D:\User\Downloads\cache\report.aux) )
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 21 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 21 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifnum on line 21 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 21 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 21 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifdim on line 21 was incomplete) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 3119 strings out of 495232
 41598 string characters out of 3181375
 104948 words of memory out of 3000000
 6354 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 11871 words of font info for 21 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 39i,4n,32p,451b,117s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
{D:/User/Documents/latex/t
exmfs/install/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}<D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/insta
ll/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmb8a.pfb><D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/fon
ts/type1/urw/times/utmr8a.pfb>
Output written on D:/User/Downloads/cache/report.pdf (1 page, 15157 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 15 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

I just noticed, it is generating the PDF, but it is without the special letters:

[image]

Comment: I tried your example and it compiles without problems with `pdflatex` on TL 2016, latest version before freeze, OS: Linux

Comment: :( I am on Windows with MikTex. I build with the command line and updated the answer within more information.

Comment: I cannot believe, you are right! Thanks you all for helping. @DavidCarlisle, you could post it as an answer, or flag to close this question.

Comment: probably irrelevant, but you have `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` twice.

Comment: Thanks, I added the second one while I was searching for a solution, however I did not noticed I already had it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save the file in UTF-8 encoding (a setting in your text editor) it runs without error.

Your file is clearly saved in latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) and produces

```
! Missing ) inserted for expression.
<to be read again> 
                   (
l.19 \section{Introdu�o}
```

So you could either use your text editor to save the file in UTF-8 or edit the line

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

to say

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```

to declare to LaTeX the encoding that the file is currently using.